# How to inflate FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-inflate, layout-inflater

I have linear Layout and I want to inflate FrameLayout into it. Do you know, how it can be done? Is it possible? I am still getting errors of **No Suitable Method Found For Inflate**

Thanks

**Edit:
answering myself:**

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
final LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
FrameLayout frml = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame,null);
frml.setId(10101010);
frml.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

ll.addView(frml);
```

Comment: Post some code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

To get the **LayoutInflater** instance you need to get it as a service like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Then you can use it to inflate the **FrameLayout** and add it to the **LinearLayout** like this

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = ... ;
inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_framelayout_file_name, linearLayout, false);
```

And don't forget to put the layout width and height for your **FrameLayout** like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    .
    .
    .
</FrameLayout>
```

For more infromation about the **LayoutInflater** [visit this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout parent = ...
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
parent.addView(view);
```

Comment: LayoutInflater.fromContext(context) -> what does it exactly do? If I pass this, it shows error

Comment: LayoutInflater.fromContext is more or less the same as getting a LayoutInflater instance from the service manager. I prefer this, since it makes more sense (LayoutInflater is not a service), and it doesn't contain a typecast. What error does it give you?

Comment: @Pal Szasz: I think you mean `LayoutInflater.from(context);`